# "sprinG summEr autumN winTer" - what does this mean?

Tags: rebus, steganography

> sprinG summEr autumN winTer

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Well the only thing that sticks out is the capitalized letter (which is steganography and not a rebus puzzle) and they spell GENT - unless the Does is intentional in which case you can add the D. Otherwise we need more information as to where this came from, what context there is/was etc.

Comment: @n_palum Silenus answer shows this is a rebus puzzle.

Comment: I saw the title and expected a puzzle that cleverly plays on the words _"Can someone please tell me what the following means?"_ that are found so often on StackExchange, but sadly the words are just used in their common way here. :-)

Comment: I'd call this a "dingbat" after the boardgame, rather than a rebus or steganography (which as far as I can tell are both more general terms).

Answer (score 36):

This could be a rebus depicting

> *[a man for all seasons](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+man+for+all+seasons)*, an idiom which means "a man who is very successful in many different types of activity". The rebus depicts the word *gent*, meaning *man*, distributed among the four seasons.

---

**EDIT:** I originally used the wrong preposition in the idiom, although the page I linked to had it correct. A now-deleted comment informed me of this. Rosie F also noticed my mistake [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51492/31484).

Answer (score 16):

Silenus has it almost right. The phrase is

> a man for all seasons

which is

> a quotation from a remark made by Robert Whittington about Sir Thomas More. A Man For All Seasons is also the title of a 1966 film about More.